# Add extra text to Pie Chart

Tags: charts, pgf-pie, pie

I would like to add extra text under the legend or next to pie chart where it looks good. But I don't know how. Can someone help me?
Would like to add: n = 77
77 is the total of all pie-pieces.
Thank you!

````
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto, radius=2, color={cyan!90, green!70, blue!40, magenta!90}, text=legend]{22/Staatstheater, 9/Landestheater, 38/Stadttheater, 8/Fusionierte Theater}
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Verteilung der Theatertypen]{Verteilung der Theatertypen}
\label{fig:verteilung_theatertypen}
\end{figure}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I use `\stackinset` to inset the extra text with the bottom right of the inset located 21 pt from the right side and 5pt from the bottom edge of the `pgf-pie` image.

I inset a 3-line `\Longstack`, which is, itself, left-aligned.

The stackinsets can be nested, as demonstrated in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\stackinset{c}{-67pt}{c}{-22pt}{wildebeasts}{%
\stackinset{r}{21pt}{b}{5pt}{%
  \Longstack[l]{$n=77$\\77 is the total\\of all pie pieces}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto, radius=2, color={cyan!90, green!70, blue!40, magenta!90}, text=legend]{22/Staatstheater, 9/Landestheater, 38/Stadttheater, 8/Fusionierte Theater}
]
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\caption[Verteilung der Theatertypen]{Verteilung der Theatertypen}
\label{fig:verteilung_theatertypen}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you!
but why isn't it working when I delete 
\stackinset{c}{-67pt}{c}{-22pt}{wildebeasts}{%

Comment: @qu33ristan You need to also remove the closing brace...there are three after the ending `tikzpicture`...make it two.

Comment: oh yes! thank you!

Comment: having an idea how to change the font size to \footnotesize?

Comment: @qu33ristan You can add `\footnotesize` immediately prior to `\Longstack` or prior to `wildebeasts` in my example.

Comment: but is it changing then all textes to that size?

Comment: @qu33ristan My comment was on how to get the inset text to `\footnotesize`, which essentially is accomplished by prepending the 5th argument of `\stackinset` (the inset) with `\footnotesize`.  If you prepend the 6th argument (the base image), right before `\begin{tikzpicture}` with `\footnotesize`, you will make the whole `tikzpicture` in that size.

Comment: awesome, it works! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote, can be used.

The legend is determined by the key `legend`. This is a `tabular` which is placed in a `\node`. The rows are determined by the key `legend row`. The result of all rows can be obtained with `\WClegend`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  data=,
  legend row={\tikz\fill[\WCvarB,draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3); & \WCvarC},
  legend={
    \node[anchor=west] at (2.5,0) {%
      \begin{tabular}{l@{ }l}%
      \WClegend%
       & $n=\WCtotalnum$\\%
       & $\WCtotalnum$ is the total\\%
       & of all pie pieces\\%
      \end{tabular}%
    };
  },
  radius={0}{2},
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black},
  start angle=0,
  wheel data={\WCvarA}
]{%
  22/cyan!90/Staatstheater,
  9/green!70/Landestheater,
  38/blue!40/Stadttheater,
  8/magenta!90/Fusionierte Theater%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```